# How to get a pygtk entry accept only floats?

Tags: python, pygtk

I want the user to be able to type only a float (that is, numbers from 0 to 9 and the decimal point should show, other characters should not). How can I do that ?

**edit**
I need to get values like "4" or "3.5" or ".9", nothing like "10e23"

Inconsistent values should also be rejected, such as "10.12.45" ...

Comment: Are there any events available for when the entry field gets a character inputted?

Comment: could the "changed" event be what we need ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally an acceptable answer thanks to SO question "How to extract a floating number from a string in Python"

```
    numeric_const_pattern = r"""
    [-+]? # optional sign
    (?:
        (?: \d* \. \d+ ) # .1 .12 .123 etc 9.1 etc 98.1 etc
        |
        (?: \d+ \.? ) # 1. 12. 123. etc 1 12 123 etc
    )
    # followed by optional exponent part if desired
    (?: [Ee] [+-]? \d+ ) ?
    """
    self.rx = re.compile(numeric_const_pattern, re.VERBOSE)
```

in the init part,

and :

```
def validate_float(self, widget, entry):
    entry_text = entry.get_text()
    newtext = self.rx.findall(entry_text)
    if len(newtext) :
        entry.set_text(newtext[0])
    else:
        entry.set_text("")
```

connected to the "changed" event of the entry. Many thanks to all those who helped.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you will get the buffer from the "changed" event.

However, it might be a good idea to have a look at connecting to the signal ["preedit-changed"](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkentry.html#signal-gtkentry--preedit-changed) in the entry itself:

> The "preedit-changed" signal is emitted when an input method is used,
>   the typed text will not immediately be committed to the buffer. So if
>   you are interested in the text, connect to this signal.

And then when you get the input you can check so that it is valid, and then manipulate the fields value accordingly.

Comment: The "changed" event passes the widget, where I can get the buffer from. The "preedit-changed" event is theoretically better but I cannot see the difference. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the event fired when the user modifies the value in the entry, and manually validate it's a float. This can be as easy as using a `try` around `float()`:

```
>>> float("1.4")
1.4
>>> float("1.4a")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1.4a
>>>
```

If an exception occurs, reject the value.

**Edit**: you can filter the characters as they are entered, too.

```
if newCharacter in "0123456789.":
    # valid
else
    # invalid
```

Comment: No, I need to catch the keys typed by the user and only show up those who are making a real float. Tanks anyway.

Comment: Your filter will accept strings as "12.34.56", which are not floats. Finally it took me a couple of hours to do it by myself; but I expected some guru to pop up in seconds, as this usually happens in SO...  ;-)

Comment: None of us provided a complete solution, but not for lack of knowledge. The question was quite simple. In these cases, here in SO we usually provide guidance, as the tips I gave you, but we don't fully implement solutions. We like to get paid for that =).
Congratulations on correctly figuring it out!